# Ion-Select is hidden behind Ion Modal

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog

Ionic version:
"@ionic/core": "^5.0.7",

If I put an ion-select inside an ion-modal, the ion-select disappear behind the modal and it's impossibile to use.

How is it possible to fix it?
I think that it's a z-index problem but I'm not able to find the css rule that fix this

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted your code to show what you hve tried so far

Comment: thank you but I solved. it was documentation problem (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
it was a documentation problem about create modals.

The doc says the wrong procedure. If the modal it's called in the correct way, the problem disappear.

Reference: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/on-select-is-hidden-behind-ion-modal/189703/7